# Independent scrollbar in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I remembered in old Visual Basic, it is possible to put a horizontal/vertical scrollbar in the form. Currently I am using Electron and want the same thing -- create an independent scrollbar, not bind to a container, and scrolling it will trigger events. Is there a way of doing so?

Comment: To provide some more details, I am trying to put some data in a *big* table. The data is generated on the fly, and the number of rows is huge. So my plan is to just generate the data that are visible, and the start index can be controlled by a scroll bar. If the scroll bar is moved, the corresponding data is generated and the view is changed.

Comment: Please do not add information about your question in a comment, edit your question, and put the information in the question itself.

Comment: you can use overflow: scroll; css property.